# Convergence test for the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series is :-

$$ \frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1+2}{1^2+2^2} + \frac{1+2+3}{1^2+2^2+3^2} + ... ∞ $$

I am unable to think for its general term.

Can anybody help me solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edits are not made for this. If you have another problem, post another question (and while doing it, try to add some personal input to your new question, an ingredient the present one is sorely lacking).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2}=\frac{3}{2n+1}$$
hence the given series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

hint
$$1+2+3+....n=\frac{n}{2}(n+1)$$
$$1+2^2+3^2+...n^2=\frac{n}{6}(n+1)(2n+1)$$
for the another series, use the ratio test
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{n^2}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)n^2}=\frac{n+1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$$
the limit is zero when $n\rightarrow \infty$, so the series converges

Comment: Thanks sir ..that was so silly of me this looks easy now ...  I don't know why I didn't think of this.